# Android crash on resume. How to interpret this exception?

Tags: java, android

I got couple of crash reports like this one and I'm not sure what does it mean.
Just to make it clear - this is something I can't reproduce. This is reported by ACRA

'Unmarshalling unknown type code 2131296357 at offset 1232'

Full error stack trace below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.idatt/com.idatt.activities.NewMailActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@40651010: Unmarshalling unknown type code 2131296357 at offset 1232
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1651)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@40651010: Unmarshalling unknown type code 2131296357 at offset 1232
 at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1913)
 at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2112)
 at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1568)
 at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1903)
 at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2083)
 at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:208)
 at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1167)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1682)
 at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:844)
 at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:816)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1096)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1629)
 ... 11 more
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcel android.os.Parcel@40651010: Unmarshalling unknown type code 2131296357 at offset 1232
 at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1913)
 at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArrayInternal(Parcel.java:2112)
 at android.os.Parcel.readSparseArray(Parcel.java:1568)
 at android.os.Parcel.readValue(Parcel.java:1903)
 at android.os.Parcel.readMapInternal(Parcel.java:2083)
 at android.os.Bundle.unparcel(Bundle.java:208)
 at android.os.Bundle.getSparseParcelableArray(Bundle.java:1167)
 at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.restoreHierarchyState(PhoneWindow.java:1682)
 at android.app.Activity.onRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:844)
 at android.app.Activity.performRestoreInstanceState(Activity.java:816)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnRestoreInstanceState(Instrumentation.java:1096)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1629)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
 at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: did you include creator?

Comment: Are you saving anything in the Bundle for `com.idatt.activities.NewMailActivity` (i.e. in `onSaveInstanceState` for that Activity)? It looks like the crash is occurring when resuming from a phone call, and it can't unmarshall one of the objects in the Bundle because it doesn't recognize the type.

Comment: Yes, I use Bundle. To be honest I was never able to hit all breakpoints in my testing of parcealable. How do I emulate this scenario when Activity terminated in my testing?

Comment: On the emulator, there should be a Dev Tools app. Open that app, select "Development Settings" from the list, and check the box next to "Immediately destroy activities". Now, when you run your app, when you hit the home button, the foreground Activity will be destroyed. You can then restart your app via long press or from the Apps screen to recreate the bug.

Comment: I would mark this comment as an answer because this is what I needed to reproduce this issue on emulator. Do you want to post it as answer?

Comment: Sure, just did. Glad it helped.

Comment: Brian did you find your bug? I have the exact same problem right now and I would appreciate a complete solution. It happens after the app has been killed (by App Killer or memory manager).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On the emulator, there should be a Dev Tools app. Open that app, select "Development Settings" from the list, and check the box next to "Immediately destroy activities". Now, when you run your app, when you hit the home button, the foreground Activity will be destroyed. You can then restart your app via long press or from the Apps screen to recreate the bug.